# How can I remove extra commas in a CSV file with php

Tags: php, csv

I'm writting a PHP script to import a CSV file to MySQL table.

My problem is that fields are separated by commas, but some fields came within an extra comma, or double quotes (I alread found the solution for double quotes), But not for extra commas.
This is an example:

```
SORT_COLUMN,SORT_ALPHA,GUEST_NAME,PROFILE_ID,FULL_ADDRESS,IS_TOTAL_YN
0,DIAZ REBOLLO ANGELICA,Diaz Rebollo Angelica,824990,"Blvd. Manuel Avila Camacho 36, piso 10   Lomas de Chapul DF 11000"
```

As you can see in the FULL ADDRESS field:

```
"Blvd. Manuel Avila Camacho 36, piso 10   Lomas de Chapul DF 11000"
```

Comes with `"` and a comma before 36,

This is part of the PHP CODE:

```
$lineseparator = "\n";
foreach(explode($lineseparator,$csvcontent) as $line) {
$lines++;
$line = trim($line," \t");
$line = str_replace("\r","",$line);

    // Here I remove double quotes in the csv file
    $line =  str_replace("&quot;",'',$line);
    $linearray = explode($fieldseparator,$line);
    $linemysql = implode("','",$linearray);
    $query = "insert into $databasetable values('$linemysql');";
    $queries .= $query . "\n";
    @mysql_query($query);
}
```

Comment: I do not know how to help you more in need in the code, but I found this link which may help you. https://raamdev.com/2007/removing-unwanted-commas-in-a-csv-file-with-php/

Comment: Oops! That page can’t be found.

Comment: `https://raamdev.com/2007/removing-unwanted-commas-in-a-csv-file-with-php/`

Comment: PHP has functions proper to read csv file, you don't have to write your own script for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fgetcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)—which is a part of the standard PHP library—is your friend.

Well, most of the time. Note, of course, the `$escape` parameter, which is weird, useless, and broken. You need to pass `0` (note: the literal integer zero, not any of the other zero-ish things in PHP) to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, working with csv, I use `;` as a field separator, and `\n` as a line separator.

Often you'll meet `,` in fields, that's why `;` is better for separating.

EDIT :

As your address field is enclosed by `"`, you can use something like this :

```
$line = '0,DIAZ REBOLLO ANGELICA,Diaz Rebollo Angelica,824990,"Blvd. Manuel Avila Camacho 36, piso 10   Lomas de Chapul DF 11000"';

preg_match('/".*"/', $line, $matches);
$address = $matches[0];

$data = explode(',', $line);

$data[4] = $address;

var_dump($data);
```

Comment: My problem is that the CSV file is generated by another system, and I cannot modify. Another idea?

Comment: I've edited my answer so it can suit your needs. Hope it helps.